Upgrading Dockerfile to Ubuntu Noble Numbat (24.04) when using msodbcsql
Background
I have some docker file to build some C++ project. Project uses MySql or MsSqlServer depending on configuration). So far I've started my docker image from ubuntu:focal and evrything was working great.
Problem
I'd like to use more modern compiler, so time has come to upgrade docker image so it is created from ubuntu:noble.
I've fixed most of the problems, but now I got compilation error:
#66 390.1 /root/SomeProduct/Src/DBConnectorMicrosoftSql.cpp:51:14: fatal error: 'msodbcsql.h' file not found
#66 390.1    51 |     #include <msodbcsql.h>
#66 390.1       |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
#66 390.1 1 error generated.

and I've failed to figure out which package should I install to resolve this silly issue.
Relevant part of my Dockerfile are looking like this:
FROM ubuntu:noble

RUN apt-get -y install curl wget gnupg
RUN apt-get -y install zip unzip tar

RUN curl -fsSL https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/microsoft-prod.gpg
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/24.04/prod.list | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends msodbcsql18 mssql-tools18 unixodbc-dev
ENV PATH=${PATH}:/opt/mssql-tools18/bin

# other steps related to C++ building process
...

Basically this was refined based on Microsoft instructions.
When trying address this issue I've added this lines to Dockerfile trying locate missing header file:
RUN apt-get install -y apt-file
RUN apt-file update
RUN apt-file find msodbcsql.h && false
# or 
RUN apt-file search msodbcsql.h && false

but search and find didn't found anything.
So how I can address this problem of missing header file?
Was it renamed? Was it moved to some other directory? Was is moved to other package?

Your header file msodbcsql.h is not in msodbcsql18, you should simply remove the line #include <msodbcsql.h> and then use the standard ODBC headers in unixodbc-dev with
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlext.h>

You also gonna have to your code use the correct ODBC functions from sql.h and dont forget to remove the msodbcsql.h reference in your Makefile if you have one.

Looks promising. Problem is that product is build also for Windows, so have to make sure this change is valid there too. This will take longer to verify then expected. Thanks.
